# How can I implement a horizontal scroll view where it aligns to each view inside when scrolled

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm trying to have a horizontal scroll view contain, for example, three vertical scroll views. And what I want is to be able to have the horizontal scroll view align to each vertical scroll view when you scroll over to it.

I'm not sure if a horizontal scroll view is the correct way to implement this kind of feature, however I found the method `scrollTo(x,y)` which I think may be in the right direction to creating this.

The best example of what I'm trying to do is shopping for music in the google play store (atleast, on my nexus 7). It allows you to scroll left or right, and it aligns to a screen's worth of content, which you can then vertically scroll.

So, that's what I'm trying to recreate in my app. But I'm confused on implementation details of allowing the horizontal scroll view, to scroll, and stop at a certain point. It looks like I need to override HorizontalScrollView to capture the motion events, but I feel like that's too complex for what seems like a simple task.

Does my question make sense? I basically am at the very starting point of creating this, and need some help as to where to go next.

Comment: try viewpager instead

Comment: To add to @apk's comment: The android support library contains the `ViewPager` component that should be suitable to your needs. Most importantly, `ViewPager` supports notification on which page is currently displayed (so you can update dependent views).